# InvalidArgumentError TensorFlow sparse_to_dense

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a sparse tensor that I'm building up from a collection of indices and values. I'm trying to implement some code to take a full row slice. Although this functionality doesn't appear to be directly supported in TensorFlow, it seems that there are work arounds that can return the indices and values for a specified row as follows:

```
def sparse_slice(self, indices, values, needed_row_ids):
    needed_row_ids = tf.reshape(needed_row_ids, [1, -1])
    num_rows = tf.shape(indices)[0]
    partitions = tf.cast(tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(tf.reshape(indices[:, 0], [-1, 1]), needed_row_ids), 1),
                         tf.int32)
    rows_to_gather = tf.dynamic_partition(tf.range(num_rows), partitions, 2)[1]
    slice_indices = tf.gather(indices, rows_to_gather)
    slice_values = tf.gather(values, rows_to_gather)
    return slice_indices, slice_values
```

Then called directly like so on a **sparse 4x4 matrix** where I am interested in accessing all of the elements in **row 3**:

```
      with tf.Session().as_default():
                indices = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 3]])
                values = tf.constant([10, 19, 1, 1, 6, 5], dtype=tf.int64)

                needed_row_ids = tf.constant([3])
                slice_indices, slice_values = self.sparse_slice(indices, values, needed_row_ids)

                  print('indicies: {} and rows: {}'.format(slice_indices.eval(), slice_values.eval()))
```

Which outputs the following:

```
indicies: [[3 0]
 [3 3]] and rows: [6 5]
```

So far so good, I then figure I can use this information to construct a **1x4 dense tensor** with the values at the indexes and 0s for the missing columns.

```
  dense_representation = tf.sparse_to_dense(sparse_values=slice_values, sparse_indices=slice_indices,
                                                   output_shape=(1,4))
```

However the moment I run the tensor in a session.

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(dense_representation)
```

I receive the following exception:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0] = [3,0] is out of bounds: need 0 <= index < [1,4]
     [[Node: SparseToDense = SparseToDense[T=DT_INT64, Tindices=DT_INT32, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Gather_2, SparseToDense/output_shape, Gather_3, SparseToDense/default_value)]]
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong or if this has something to do with the `output_shape` not being properly formed. Essentially I'd like to stuff this all back into a 1 x 4 vector. I haven't been able to find any good examples online for how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?